# vowels at front and consonants at back in string as linked list

Tags: java, string

I have given the input AMAZON through a linked list.Output should be AAOMZN.ie vowels at front and consonants at back.Netbeans IDE isn't showing any output.Please point out error if any.Why is the IDE not showing any output. 
My code :

```
    class Node
    {
    char value;
    Node next;

    }
    public class AmazonProb1 
    {
    public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    String str=s.nextLine();

    StringTokenizer ss=new StringTokenizer(str);
    Node a1=new Node();
    Node a2=new Node();
    Node a3=new Node();
    Node a4=new Node();
    Node a5=new Node();
    Node a6=new Node();
    a1.value='A'; 
    a2.value='M'; 
    a3.value='A'; 
    a4.value='Z';
    a5.value='O'; 
    a6.value='N';


    a1.next=a2;
    a2.next=a3;
    a3.next=a4;
    a4.next=a5;
    a5.next=a6;
    a6.next=null;








    Node x=new Node();
    Node head=new Node();
    head=a1;
    x=a1;


    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {  
    if(head.value==(('A')|('O')|('E')|('I')|('U'))) 
    {
        head=head.next;

    }
    else if(head.value!=(('A')|('O')|('E')|('I')|('U'))) 
    {
        x=head;
        while(head.value!=(('A')|('O')|('E')|('I')|('U'))) 
        {
            x=x.next;

        }
        swap(x,head);


        }

    }                


    System.out.println(a1);
    System.out.println(a2);  
    System.out.println(a3);  
    System.out.println(a4); 
    System.out.println(a5);  
    System.out.println(a6);   


    }

    public static void swap(Node a,Node b)
    {
    Node temp=new Node();
    temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;

    }

    }
```

Comment: a e i o u, not a o e i u...pat sayjak would be devastated.  By the way what kind of language is this?  You need to say if head.value == 'A' || head.value == 'O' ||...)

Comment: it is java..was confused about the OR thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing out the node, not node.value. Also, you don't need to create a new node for Temp before assigning it b. b is already a reference to a node. You do not need another.

Comment: @taashu - based on your code the compiler is doing everything correctly.  Take a step back and revisit your code I see a lot of issues.  Then re-post all the changes you made to your code.

Comment: x=x.next; i do not understnd why?

Comment: @taashu - do you happen to have a debugger?  If so please use it.

Comment: as the last node is defined to null,my code is trying to access the null pointer?

Comment: idk, is it? You are trying to call println with a node, not a string. That might be your first problem. If all else fails, draw pointer diagrams on a piece of paper. It will help you visualize what's going on.

Comment: ya i corrected the println problem.Is there any better way to iterate through the linked list?